# How to add page number on OpenHtmlToPdf on every page?

Tags: c#, openhtmltopdf

I am using nuget "OpenHtmlToPdf" version="1.12.0.0" on .net c# api project. This project is based on
OpenHtmlToPdf however I am not sure how we can add page number at bottom of each generate page.

Below are the only code I found on github page.

```
 var pdf = Pdf
                .From(contents)
                .OfSize(PaperSize.A4)
                .WithTitle($"Report Data")
                .WithoutOutline()
                .WithObjectSetting("web.defaultEncoding", "utf-8")
                .WithObjectSetting("pagesCount", "true")
                .Portrait()
                .Comressed()
                .Content();
```

Is it possible to add footer with page number ? I noticed on the setting
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/libwkhtmltox/pagesettings.html there is only one option to add header.htmlUrl (footer.htmlUrl) & pagesCount but clear example how to implement or achieve.

nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf/

Comment: Can you share the nuget link please? Your link differs from the nuget package name

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary added on description

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm facing the same problem.